# Comparing in Array

Tags: c#

There is something wrong with my code.  I am teaching myself c# and one of the challenges in this chapter was to prompt the user for 10 numbers, store them in an array, than ask for 1 additional number.  Then the program would say whether the additional number matched one of the numbers in the array.  Now what I have below does work, but only if I enter in a comparison number that is less than 10 which is the size of the array.

I'm not sure how to fix it.  I am not sure how to do the comparison.  I tried a FOR loop first which kind of worked, but ran through the loop and displayed the comparison against all 10 numbers so you would get 9 lines of No! and 1 line of Yes!.  I put in a break; which stopped it counting all 10 but if I entered the number 5 for comparison, then I would get 4 lines of No! and 1 of Yes!.  The below has been the only way I could get it to work reliably but only as long as the number isn't out of the bounds of the array.

I can see why I get the error when the number is above 10, I just don't know what to use to compare it but still allow the user to enter in any valid integer.  Any assistance would be great!

```
        int[] myNum = new int[10];
        Console.WriteLine("Starting program ...");
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter 10 numbers.");

        for (int i = 0; i <= 9; ++i)
        {
            Console.Write("Number {0}: ", i + 1);
            myNum[i] = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Thank you.  You entered the numbers ");
        foreach (int i in myNum)
        {
            Console.Write("{0} ", i);
        }

        Console.WriteLine("");
        Console.Write("Please enter 1 additional number: ");
        int myChoice = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("Thank you.  You entered the number {0}.", myChoice);

        int compareArray = myNum[myChoice - 1];

        if (compareArray == myChoice)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Yes!  The number {0} is equal to one of the numbers you previously entered.", myChoice);
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("No!  The number {0} is not equal to any of the entered numbers.", myChoice);
        }

        Console.WriteLine("End program ...");

        Console.ReadLine();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you include the System.Linq namespace (or if you change the type of myNum to be something that implements [ICollection<T>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/92t2ye13.aspx), like `List<T>`), you can use `myNum.Contains(myChoice)` to see if the value `myChoice` matches one of the values in `myNum`.  `array.Contains` returns a boolean that is `true` if the specified value is found in the array and `false` if it is not.

You can update your code to use this like so:

```
   //int compareArray = myNum[myChoice - 1]; // This line is no longer needed

    if (myNum.Contains(myChoice))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Yes!  The number {0} is equal to one of the numbers you previously entered.", myChoice);
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("No!  The number {0} is not equal to any of the entered numbers.", myChoice);
    }
```

Comment: Note that the `.Contains()` method will not compile unless you also have `using System.Linq;` in your .cs file.  It is an "extension method" provided by Linq, and not a method on the array class.

Comment: Using System.Linq; is included by default when I create a new C# Console App. This worked really well. So very very simple.

Answer (score 4):

You were on the right track- you want to loop through the array in myNum and compare each element to the variable myChoice. If you don't want to print whether each element of the array is a match, create a new variable and use it to keep track of whether you've found a match or not. Then after the loop you can check that variable and print your finding. You'd usually use a bool variable for that- set it false to start, then true when you find a match.

```
bool foundMatch = false;
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    if (myNum[i] == myChoice) {
        foundMatch = true;
    }
}
if (foundMatch) {
    Console.WriteLine("Yes!  The number {0} is equal to one of the numbers you previously entered.", myChoice);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for numbers that are definitely between 1 and 10, then before you use

```
int compareArray = myNum[myChoice - 1];
```

check if it's over the value of 10. For example:

```
while(myChoice > 10)
{
    Console.Write("Please choose a number less than or equal to 10: ");
    myChoice = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
}
```

The benefit of putting it inside a `while` loop instead of an `if` tag means that, when the user enters another number, the value of `myChoice` will be rewritten, and compared against. If they enter a number over 10, it'll keep responding `Please choose a number less than or equal to 10.` until the number they input is below or equal to 10:` Then, your program will continue.

However, if you want to compare it against the array, rather than put in a fixed number comparison, consider the following `while` loop:

```
while(myChoice > myNum.Length)
{
    Console.Write("Please choose a number less than or equal to {0}: ", myNum.Length);
    myChoice = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
}
```

This will work for any sized array then, without you having to change the `while` loops content. By using this system, you can then ensure that you won't get an `IndexOutOfBounds` exception, so long as you subtract 1 when using it as an index.

Comment: The only problem with the first part is that in the original problem the array holds a list of 10 arbitrary numbers (not specifically the numbers 1-10).

Comment: I realize, but he was trying to run the input as an index. This solves the `IndexOutOfBounds`exception.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking to compare a final, 11th value and trying to determine if its in an array of 10 previous entries?

Try:

```
for(int i = 0; i < array.length - 1; i++;)
{
    If(array[i] == input)
        return true;
}

 return false;
```

You should be able to figure out how to implement this completely yourself, as you did want to do it as an exercise.

Edit: If someone wants to check this or complete it in correct syntax, go ahead. I posted this rough outline from a phone.